# Есть ли возможность сверстать такую раскладку с помощью column-count?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть ли возможность сверстать такую раскладку с помощью column-count? Или с помощью чего такое можно сделать? Если не брать в расчет grid и flex[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему grid не брать в расчет?

Comment: Просто прохожу курс по верстке и препод сделал похожую сетку с помощью column-count и в домашку дал самостоятельно вот это сделать, а grid мы еще не проходили по плану, то есть не подразумевается что мы это должны знать. Вот я и интересуюсь можно ли такое сделать без грида

Comment: В [теории](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout) можно, на практике не самый популярный способ. Попробуйте — расскажете...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так.

Только учтите, что `column-span` не везде поддерживается.

Два блока `.container' нужны потому, что нельзя с помощью` column-span` растянуть блок только на часть столбцов - или на все, или никак.

```css
.block {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.one {
  background-color: pink;
}

.two {
  background-color: wheat;
  column-span: all;
}

.container {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block two">A</div>
    <div class="block one">B</div>
    <div class="block one">C</div>
    <div class="block one">D</div>
    <div class="block one">E</div>
    <div class="block two">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```